# Stackdriver stdout log message severity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stdout, stackdriver

I am using a none supported language on GCP.

Stackdriver logging is great it collects my stdout logs which is most excellent.

However I can't seem to set a severity.

All the documentation pages seem to revolve around sending whole logs.

I would like to know what a message needs to look like when sending it to stdout so it picks up on the severity. An Example would be amazing.

Comment: What environment are you running your application in?  For example, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, GKE, Compute Engine or something else?

Comment: @Kolban Cloud Run which rocks by the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be some quite good documentation on writing stdout/stderr output from your apps and how this translates to Stackdriver output found [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#container-logs).

If you write a JSON string to output the structure will be parsed.

Documentation on special fields can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields).

In summary,

- severity

  - DEFAULT
  - DEBUG
  - INFO
  - NOTICE
  - WARNING
  - ERROR
  - CRITICAL
  - ALERT
  - EMERGENCY
- message
- log
- ... others

The content of your output will appear in the `jsonPayload` field of the Stackdriver record entry.

An example sent to stdout might be:

```
{
  "severity": "NOTICE",
  "message": "Hello World!",
  "additional-part": "More Data!"
}
```

Comment: I saw those docs but was confused by the header and trace References...if they had included a simple example it really would have helped...thanks I am giving it a try now

Comment: Please do give it a try ... if you hit a puzzle, be sure and post back and we'll look at it together.